# Does a server put in a 19-inch rack require CE marking?

Tags: testing, ce

If I sell to a european customer a simple 1U rack-mount server in a 19-inch rack, do I need to test the conformity of the whole "thing"?
The server itself has CE mark, not sure about the 19-inch rack (as I don't know whether CE marking is mandatory for this kind of product).

What if the 19-inch rack includes PDUs (which are CE marked)?

Comment: Fairly sure the answer is "no" although as with most things CE this is hard to source. Presumably it would ship disassembled?

Comment: @pjc50 yes but we are also responsible for on-site installation

Comment: Speak with the server rack sellers.

Comment: The PDUs will need CE marking.

Comment: @BrianDrummond sure, they have. Updated question for clarity

Comment: Are you supplying any wiring (other than pre-assembled cables?) I am leaning towards self-certification here, allowing you to apply your own CE marking, and maintain a TCF (Technical Construction File) basically stating that each component is CE marked (along withtheir own certificates) and that combining them does not introduce new hazards (such as fire because you have complied with the server's cooling requirements X,Y and the wiring meets standard Z). Read more about CE self-certification. You may want professional help writing your first TCF but I don't see any testing required.

Comment: You need to make a case in your documentation (technical file) where you point our the CE marking of every individual server and then argue how bringing them together should not affect relevant directives/standards. In this case probably EMC and LVD directives + a whole bunch of standards. I would imagine that things like combined heat and other environmental aspects need to be taken in account, as part of product safety.

Comment: @BrianDrummond we just supply pre-assembled cables. Technically, I agree with everything you wrote. But legally, should I literally put a CE mark on the "product"? Can a Rack+PDU+Server be considered a product? How would that differ from supplying a desk (with power outlet) with a computer on top?

Comment: In short: Yes all seperate parts or the product as a whole needs CE Markings. CE markings are not specific to electrical products. "The CE marking is the manufacturer's declaration that the product meets EU standards for health, safety, and environmental protection" You also guarantee the color of your rack has no harming substances as defined by european standards or e.g. conform to flammability tests and such...

Comment: Also important: "The manufacturer must carry out a conformity assessment, set up a technical file, and sign a Declaration stipulated by the leading legislation for the product. The documentation has to be made available to authorities on request." - so the CE Mark is just the icing on the  cake. What counts is, you have done the paperwork

Comment: @schnedan a rack without PDUs is subject to CE mark? Which directive specifically? It cannot be EMC (no active components), or LVD (nothing electrical), or RoHS (which AFAIK applies to electronic devices)...

Comment: @kuma a rack with nothing in it maybe not as it is a unfinished product*, but just to be sure I would do an CE assessment to check if CE rules do not apply. Or as a engineering service specialized in CE consulting. *but anyone who will build a finished product with it might need to do the documentation,...

Comment: Suggest that you sell them all seperately. Any existing CE compliance is then retained. A simple rack is incapable of being tested so no CE mark can legally be attached as it's not 'an equipment' within the scope of the regulations.

Comment: @schnedan I'm confused. To me, a rack is indeed a "product". While "a rack with a server in it" is not, in the same way that "a desk" is indeed a product, while "a desk with a computer sitting on it" is not.

Comment: @kuma The Problem is, the topic is very broad. I just tried to tell what the general sites of the eu say. https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/manufacturers_en , https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/ maybe a rack is part of whats defined as machine and machines are defined also by parts and unfinished partial machines... You better mandate a professional agency to check what you are required to do

Comment: EU Blue Guide: https://ec.europa.eu/docsroom/documents/18027/attachments/1/translations/en/renditions/native

Comment: for a server this might apply https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32014L0035&from=EN#d1e893-357-1

Answer (score 2):

If the rack in question is just a "dumb metal component" containing no electronics, no shielding for the purpose of EMC, is not purposely used as antenna ground and does not contribute negatively to radio or EMC when used in the intended environment, then you are excluded from most of the EU directives regarding electronics.

The [EMC Directive 2014/30/EU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32014L0030) has the following exception in its scope (Article 2):

> This Directive shall not apply to:
> /--/
> (d) equipment the inherent nature of the physical characteristics of which is such that:
>
> (i) it is incapable of generating or contributing to electromagnetic emissions which exceed a level allowing radio and telecommunication equipment and other equipment to operate as intended; and
>
> (ii) it operates without unacceptable degradation in the presence of the electromagnetic disturbance normally consequent upon its intended use;

RED and LVD directives will have similar wordings. RoHS does indeed only apply to electronics. You may however still have to take the WEEE and REACH environmental directives in account, regarding recycling and banned chemicals. Depending on what your product contains - be wary of cadmium and various flame retardants in particular.

Comment: It’s true that if you just sell the rack, you don’t need to consider EMC. However, if you sell a rack and a server, either as a complete unit or as separate components to be assembled by the end-user, then you fall under the EMC regulations.

Comment: @user110971 Yep, whoever puts the whole thing together as the final product ends up with all responsibilities including CE marking.

Comment: @Lundin WEEE and REACH are not CE marking directives/regulations, are they?

Comment: @kuma Not WEEE, though it comes with other marking (the garbage bin). I'm not certain about REACH.

Comment: @user110971 "if you sell a rack and a server [...] then you fall under the EMC regulations" does the same apply if I sell a computer and a desk?

Comment: @kuma Are they separate products? Is the desk specifically designed to fit said computer? I guess one can make an argument that a desk can be used for other things. See the definition of apparatus in my answer. Even if you need the CE marking, you’ll just self-certify. For these edge cases you really need specialized legal advice.

Comment: @kuma If you sell a rack that allow lots of computers to sit close together, someone at some point has to consider the combined EMI and heat from all those computers. The responsibility ultimately falls on whoever puts the final item on the market. Unless each server is to be regarded as a separate end product.

Comment: Note that to cover (i) and (ii) you really need to test it, making the exception rather pointless.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson No, this is the scope of the EMC Directive. I can conclude that a bag of peanuts doesn't contribute to EMI just fine without hiring a test house :)

Comment: Well ... certain exceptions are valid such as a battery powered flashlight (no feasible means of radiating energy) other than luminous ! There is a lack of clarity as to what an 'equipment' actually means. Typical of civil servants draughting rules for engineers ! Also there are separate rules concerning 'installations', into which category, narrowly the above falls. This requires on site testing. To avoid this, sell/export it as individual compliant items and quietly assemble on site.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson Yes, this is a huge problem with EU legislation. Bureaucrats drafting rules even though they have no practical experience of _anything_, including how to run a company or indeed engineering. And so they assume that every company out there is Microsoft-sized and can hire their own "Directive expert" who sits and read directives and standards all day long. In practice almost every company is cutting corners with these directives at some extent. Particularly when they go against common sense, which is often the case.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a legal question so: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. Now that's out of the way, it seems that you indeed need to place a CE mark on your product. Here is what the legislation in the  U.K. requires:

Requirements for placing on the market

> 15. No person shall place on the market apparatus unless either the following requirements, or the corresponding requirements of the EMC
>     Directive as implemented under the law of another state in the
>     Community, are met—
>
> (a)the apparatus is compliant with the essential requirements;
>
> (b)compliance with the essential requirements has been demonstrated in
> accordance with regulation 18;
>
> (c)the technical documentation
> including any statement issued by a notified body under regulation 20
> has been prepared and is available to the enforcement authority on
> request;
>
> (d)the CE marking has been properly affixed by the manufacturer or his authorised representative in accordance with regulation 21;
>
> (e)an EC declaration of conformity has been issued in
> accordance with the requirements of regulation 22;
>
> (f)each apparatus
> is identified in terms of type, batch, serial number or any
> information allowing for identification of the apparatus;
>
> (g)each
> apparatus is accompanied by the name and address of the manufacturer
> and if he is not established in the Community, the name and address of
> the responsible person;
>
> (h)the manufacturer has provided information
> on any specific precautions that must be taken when the apparatus is
> assembled, installed, maintained or used in order to ensure that when
> put into service the apparatus complies with the essential
> requirements;
>
> (i)apparatus for which compliance with the essential
> requirements is not ensured in residential areas is accompanied by a
> clear indication of this restriction of use and where appropriate this
> indication is also on the packaging; and
>
> (j)the information required
> to enable the apparatus to be used in accordance with its intended
> purpose is contained in the instructions accompanying the apparatus.

This is from [The Electromagnetic Compatibility Regulations 2006](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2006/3418/regulation/15/made). Look at (d). It specifically prohibits you to put a device on the market, if you have not affixed the CE marking to the device, or to the packaging, if there is not enough space, as stated in 21.

An apparatus is defines as:

> 3.—(1) In these Regulations, “apparatus” means any finished appliance or combination of appliances made commercially available as a single functional unit, intended for the end user and liable to generate electromagnetic disturbance, or the performance of which is liable to be affected by such disturbance and includes—
>
> (a) components or sub-assemblies intended for incorporation into an apparatus by an end-user, which are liable to generate electromagnetic disturbance, or the performance of which is liable to be affected by such disturbance;
>
> (b) mobile installations defined as a combination of apparatus and, where applicable, other devices, intended to be moved and operated in a range of locations;

The only exceptions are:

> 17. The requirements in regulation 15 and 16 shall not apply to—
>
> (a)the placing on the market of apparatus before 20th July 2009; and
>
> (b)the putting into service of apparatus placed on the market before
> 20th July 2009, where, on or before 19th July 2007, a declaration of
> conformity in respect of such apparatus has been issued by the
> manufacturer or his authorised representative pursuant to Article 10.1
> or 10.2 of Directive 89/336/EEC as implemented in the United Kingdom
> to enable it to be placed on the market or put into service, or both.

And electromagnetically benign equipment:

> 8. These Regulations do not apply to equipment the inherent qualities of which are such that—
>
> (a)it is incapable of generating or contributing to electromagnetic
> emissions which exceed a level allowing radio and telecommunication
> equipment and other equipment to operate as intended; and
>
> (b)it will
> operate without unacceptable degradation in the presence of
> electromagnetic disturbance normally consequent upon its intended use.

Comment: Only valid until 2022 when you will need a UKCA mark instead.

Comment: These would be pre-Brexit rules so it's basically the EMC directive which applies universally to the whole EU. However, you are missing the scope part.

Comment: @pipe Who knows what’s going to happen. I expect little to change initially. You’ll need to put the new marking but underneath the regulations will be virtually identical. I gave the UK as an example because, although similar laws are present in other jurisdictions, the UK statutes are written in English.

Comment: @Lundin It was getting a bit long for an answer. It should point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: But WHO checks anyway ???

Comment: @GrahamStevenson The regulator and your competitors. You are right that many devices, especially from small manufacturers, on the market are not compliant. However, If something bad happens, it is a good idea to be EMC compliant. Breaking the above legislation carries an unlimited fine and a prison sentence of up to three months.

Comment: Oh, I'm entirely aware of that. When CE compliance became mandatory, I heard that UK Trading Standards unwisely attempted a case based on their misunderstanding of the legislation ! Once bitten, twice shy ! They don't have the funds to police it anyway. Note that in my other comments, I advised not to ignore it but rather evade the problem of getting compliance for an installation. It's all completely bonkers. Many get the dimensions and/or spacing of the 'CE mark' wrong too, which is also an offence but I don't see anyone being hauled up for it ! CE has just given compliance a bad rep.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson There’s a due diligence defense. Basically, if you do a reasonable effort, you are safe.

Comment: Also true. At least the worst you'll get is a rap on the knuckles (plus a fine most likely !). Are you aware of any successful CE prosecutions ? BTW, I wrote a pamphlet on CE compliance when it came in to explain it. It was included in all our products for about a year.

Comment: @GrahamStevenson Don’t know about prosecutions, but legal takes compliance issues extremely seriously. I know of entire products delayed due to EMC. That’s for a large company though. You can bet that every single product is being tested by various competitors.

Comment: Presumably rather large. My own involvement has been with companies around £5 million turnover, so safety and EMC compliance has to be done very cost sensitively. I believe we did a good job though. Pretty damn thorough. I always used the same Consultant, one Eddie Rubin who helped set up the former ICL's EMC testing facility in a disused salt mine in Cheshire,

Comment: @GrahamStevenson Yes, a large company with its own EMC chamber and everything.